# GitHub Initial Commit on Ubuntu - Failed to push some refs

Tags: ubuntu, github, command-line-interface

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

In Ubuntu command line interface, I'm trying to make a initial commit to a new repo but I'm receiving the following error message:

> ! [rejected] master -> master (fetch first) error: failed to push
>   some refs to 'git@github.tools/splunk-christest2-app.git' hint:
>   Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>   hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository
>   pushing hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the
>   remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for
>   details. chris@chris-9550:~/Documents/GitHub/splunk-christest2-app$
>   chris@chris-9550:~/Documents/GitHub/splunk-christest2-app$

This is the process I'm following.

- Created the empty repo on GitHub Enterprise
- Created a local folder with repo content.
- Entered **git init** in Terminal to initialise the the repo
- Entered **git remote add origin (repo URL)**
- Entered **git add .**
- Entered **git commit -m "Initial Commit"**
- Entered **git push origin master**

I've looked through various sites which seem to suggest that I'm following the correct process.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Comment: Are you sure you created an empty repo and did not generate a `README.md` or `.gitignore` ? You're error is saying your remote repository is not empty, so you should do git pull first before you push.

Comment: Hi @Deb, yes you are quite right I did some more research in this and found that to be the case.

Thank you for taking the time to reply to my post.

Regards